# Get integer value from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, integer

In my JTable i have 4 columns where last 3 columns are set as integer. I used netbeans Table Contents to change the column type from `Object` to `Integer` I also initialized

```
jTable1.getModel().getColumnClass(1);
jTable1.getModel().getColumnClass(2);
```

and to retrieve the value i used `getValueAt`

```
int qty=(int)jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1);
int amt=(int)jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2);
```

But it's showing this error

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

What I'm missing here? Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Easy answer, but you still haven't accepted an answer from you previous question, so I'll skip this one.

Comment: I can guess it's an easy answer but some how i'm not geeting it :) i just tried your answer and accepted it.

Comment: Well, that wasn't what I was really talking about since you already accepted an answer. I just suggested there was an easier solution if you wanted to try it. You still have other questions that do not have an accepted answer. You should be resolving old questions before you ask new questions.

Comment: But i mentioned that it worked !! and i didn't know about the accepted answer thing i'm a new member.

Comment: `i didn't know about the accepted answer thing` you accepted two answers without prompting from anybody. You still have an outstanding question on "currency renderers". If the suggestions didn't help then you should also comment. Regarding this question, I suggest you read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for a working example that uses Integers in one of the columns. I don't have any more time to spend.

Comment: I solved it using Interger.parseInt(the string) @camickr

Comment: that is NOT the proper solution. If you add an Integer to the TableModel then you should be able to retrieve an Integer from the TableModel. Did you even read the tutorial and download the demo example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this INTEGER.parseInt(getvalueat(2,4)); this should be able to allow you to put it into an int